# php generates an empty string while received encoded string via ajax post method?

Tags: php

Although it is heard in the forums that PHP automatically converts encoded strings sent via AJAX GET or POST method. I have sent data by using ajax post method which is encoded using encodeURIComponent() function. My code segment is:

```
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
   var url = "decode.php";
   var param = "name=" + name;

   ajaxRequest.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-length", param.length);
ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

    ajaxRequest.send(encodeURIComponent(param));
```

When the server receives it,and if I try to echo it like (the result is displayed via ajax response) it displays only empty string:

```
<?php
 $content = $_POST['name'];
 echo $content;
?>
```

How do I get PHP to return the correct input string? I am confused!

Comment: Why not use Jquery Ajax: `http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/` ?

Comment: Have you tried `print_r($_REQUEST);` in your PHP script to see if anything at all is received by the script?

Comment: Your mistake is that you encode the _whole_ `name=value` string, which encodes the `=` as well, and thereby takes its special meaning _away_. Encode the value only (or the parameter name as well, if your script might encounter parameter names with “special characters” as well). Or let jQuery handle that for you, as @Nil'z already suggested.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks a lot for your valuable help. I tried to echo the results and they were quite satisfactory. That is for example, if I input #124 then PHP echoes #124 or for input &127 PHP prints exactly &127, but if I input say &#123 then PHP just inputs {.I don't know why..... again confused